# CSS transitions over tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-transitions

I am trying to write a html page containing a table and when the mouse is over the table, it should collapse to the table header. This collapse operation should be done with transitions/animations.

I have no idea how to do transitions when I have a table. I couldn't find any example online. Can someone please explain?

Below is my code, but it only creates a table formatted using a style sheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #F0F0F0}
th {
    background-color: #FF3366;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
   <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Firstname</th>
         <th>Lastname</th>
         <th>Savings</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td>$100</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td>$150</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Swanson</td>
        <td>$300</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Cleveland</td>
       <td>Brown</td>
       <td>$250</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use thead and tbody, then try to apply a transition to the tbody on the max-height property (from 0 to a really high value)

Comment: You want to *collapse* when the mouse is *over* the table? Trying to visualize the use-case, and it feels like that would be incredibly annoying for a user, but more than that, if you collapse the table, presumably the mouse will no longer be over it - what should happen then? Table expands again, then the mouse is over it again, so it collapses again? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: *really high value* Probably a "pretty high value' would work better. Otherwise some large proportion of the transition time will be spent getting down from or up to the really high value to the actual height, and only the remaining time on getting down from or up to the actual height from zero.

Comment: Yes, it is not a very useful thing what I'am trying to do, but is for a school requirement.. you are understanding correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css

```
thead:hover+tbody{
    display: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

and html structure will be

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Savings</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>Griffin</td>
                <td>$100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lois</td>
                <td>Griffin</td>
                <td>$150</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joe</td>
                <td>Swanson</td>
                <td>$300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cleveland</td>
                <td>Brown</td>
                <td>$250</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this axample: [EXAMPLE](https://www.w3.org/Talks/2012/0416-CSS-WWW2012/Demos/transitions/demo-transitions-2.html)

> In this case, Generally used `transision` property.